# Using applescript with Calendar in El Capitan

Tags: applescript, calendar, apple-configurator

I've been trying for weeks to script an ipad restore process for Apple Configurator 2.  My script works fine when ran within Script Editor, and it also works as a stand alone application.  The problem occurs when my script is launched from a Calendar event (which is the whole idea so I don't have to run it manually).  Here is the first part of my script:

```
tell application "Apple Configurator 2"
activate
delay 30
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Apple Configurator 2"
        keystroke "a" using {command down}
        delay 5
        click menu item "1 - Erase" of menu 1 of menu item "Apply" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Actions" of menu bar 1
        delay 5
        click button "Apply" of sheet 1 of window "All Devices"
    end tell
end tell
```

The script triggers just fine, and all is working until it attempts to click the "Apply" button.  My script application returns this error:
Can't get window "All Devices" of <> "Apple Configurator 2" of application 
"System Events".

System Events got an error: Can't get window "All 
Devices" of process "Apple Configurator 2". (-1728)

As an Applescript newbie, I'm out of ideas. Anybody else?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Code does not work as is. I have tested this and it works.

```
tell application "Apple Configurator 2"
activate
delay 30
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "a" using {command down}
    delay 5
    click menu item "1 - Erase" of menu 1 of menu item "Apply" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Actions" of menu bar 1
    delay 5
    click button "Apply" of sheet 1 of window "All Devices"
end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Please keep me updated.

Comment: Hmm, not able to get as far as before.  Now I get "Can't get <<class mbar>> 1 of application "System Events". System Events got an error: Can't get menu bar 1. (-1728)

Comment: Which would make sense because menu bar 1 would belong to Configurator not System Events, right?